# php script not sending mail using phpmailer when using a cronjob but does mail when accessing script directly

Tags: php, email, cron

I have a script that sends an email using phpmailer.

This is my script:

```
<?PHP
require "/home/websitename/public_html/new/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php";
// Connectie script
class Connection {
    // Configure Database Vars
    private $host     = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'username';
    private $password = 'mypass';
    private $db_name  = 'mydbname';
    public $db;

    function __construct() {
        // Create connection
        $db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
        // Check connection
        if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
            die('Unable to connect to the database: '.$db->connect_error);
        }
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $db = $this->db;
        $this->db->query('SET NAMES utf8');
        if (!$result = $this->db->query($query)) {
            die('There was an error running the query ['.$db->error.']');
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function multi_query($query) {
        $db = $this->db;
        if (!$result = $this->db->multi_query($query)) {
            die('There was an error running the multi query ['.$db->error.']');
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function real_escape_string($value) {
        return $this->db->real_escape_string($value);
    }

    public function inserted_id() {
        return $this->db->insert_id;
    }
}

$conn = new Connection();

$getaccounts = 'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE verified_email = 0';
$getaccountscon = $conn->query($getaccounts);
while($getaccounts = $getaccountscon->fetch_assoc()){
  $timer = strtotime($getaccounts['timer']);

  $time = '1 minuut voorbij van account van '.$getaccounts['voornaam'];
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->From = 'noreply@website.nl';
  $mail->FromName = 'website.nl';
  $mail->addAddress('twan@website.nl');
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->Subject = 'Verifieer je e-mail bij website.nl';
  $mail->msgHTML($time);
  if(!$mail->send())
  {
    echo 'Er is iets foutgegaan tijdens het verzenden van de verificatie mail';
  }
}

?>
```

When I open it directly through the browser, it works fine. But when I use it in a cronjob I get no emails at all. This is my cronjob command: `wget -O /dev/null -quiet https://mywebsite.nl/new/includes/checkemailverify.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

What can be causing the issue?

Comment: Have you tried _not_ using `wget` but calling the script directly via `php` in your cronjob?

Comment: Shell and web has different properties: users, envs and other.

Comment: @kerbholz Yes I tried that before with no result, that's why I tried doing it through the browser.

Comment: give a full path to wget in your crontab.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Can you give me an example? I'm not really familiar with cronjobs.

Comment: on my box, the fully qualified  path of wget is  : `/usr/local/bin/wget` ... to know on your box, you can issue `which wget` command at the terminal, while logged in as the crontab user (assuming you are running on an OS).  Edit your crontab to have the fully qualified path of wget, and make certain it is readable and executable by the crontab user.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I am running it through cPanel on my hosting package and I don't have terminal access. Is there another way or do I need to contact the hosting provider?

Comment: @twan : i know skwat about cPanel.  But if you can modify the crontab (config for cron), you could ask your provider for the fully qualified path of wget, and edit the crontab as per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The user running the cron may have a different user than your web server's user. So there may be some environment variables like **PATH** that could be undefined, and cron be unable to find `wget`. To fix **PATH** you must provide in crontab the fully qualified path th `wget`.

Assuming you are on a *nix box, login as the user whose crontab will be executed. Find where wget is on your file system:

```
DarkMax:~ yvesleborg$ which wget
/usr/local/bin/wget
DarkMax:~ yvesleborg$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/wget
lrwxr-xr-x  1 yvesleborg  admin  30 27 Sep  2018 /usr/local/bin/wget -> ../Cellar/wget/1.19.5/bin/wget
```

Notice, that wget is executable by system user `yvesleborg`.  Make certain it is for the user running the cron job.

Then edit your crontab

```
crontab -e
```

and change wget to the fully qualified path you got above. In your case that would make your command :

```
/fully/qualified/path/to/wget -O /dev/null -quiet https://mywebsite.nl/new/includes/checkemailverify.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```